# Using Ext.Panel how do I specify a .php page as the html source?

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

I have an existing panel where I set the html manually with a variable like so:

```
s = '<H1>My Html Page';
s += '[more html]]';

 var panel = new Ext.Panel({
            id: 'service_Billing',
            title: 'Billing',
            tbar: [],
            html: s
        });
```

How can I specify a path on same server server of a .php file instead of the variable as the source of the html. Something like /path/example/data.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [`autoLoad`](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Panel.html#cfg-Ext.Panel-autoLoad).

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
  autoLoad: '/path/example/data.php',
  id: 'service_Billing',
  title: 'Billing',
  tbar: []
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Ext.Ajax to grab the content and update the panel:

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel(...);
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: '/your/script.php',
  success: function(response,opts){
    opts.panel.update(response.responseText);
  },
  panel: panel
});
```

Or something like that ought to do it.

Comment: There is no `panel` config on Ajax.request -- do you mean `scope`?  Panel's `autoLoad` config as shown by @wombleton is the best approach.

Comment: scope would work too (and is probably better).  I just wanted a reference to the panel inside the handler (here: opts.panel).  This does work.